# execve with sed fails

Tags: c, sed

I'm creating a small unix shell, execve has an issue with `sed`. When I execute `sed -e 's/Roses/Turnips/'` the command fails with execve.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int ac, char **av, char **envp)
{
    char *argv[] = { "/usr/bin/sed", "-e", "'s/Roses/Turnips/'", 0 };
    execve(argv[0], &argv[0], envp);
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed!\n");
    return -1;
}
```

Error:

```
/usr/bin/sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''
```

Comment: have you tried escaping the single quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the single quotes around the `s///` argument. Those are part of shell syntax, not `sed` syntax.

```
char *argv[] = { "/usr/bin/sed", "-e", "s/Roses/Turnips/", 0 };
```

`execve` executes the program directly, it doesn't use a shell. Every argument is sent literally to the program, so no escaping or quoting is needed as when running a program in the shell.

Comment: and execve doesn't execute a shell.

Answer (score 0):

That problem arises inside of `sed` because it doesn't want your single quotes.
You'd use those single quotes in a shell to prevent it from interpreting the sed command, but the shell would ultimately remove those quotes, which is what you need to do also.